# Can a process builder trigger a workflow field update?

Tags: process-builder, field-update, workflowrule

I have an object (let's call it Object2), which has a lookup to account.

Object2 has a field called combined, which concatenates the value of account.Customer type and a few other fields (including a large text area field).

The issue I have is that when the account customer type gets changed, the field update workflow doesn't get triggered.

I wanted to solve this issue in this way: created a field called customer type in Object2, added a process builder to update customer type field. So far this works fine, ie updating the account customer type will cause the object2 customer type to be updated.

But still this change doesn't trigger the workflow field update to update the combined field.

I can see that last modified values are showing the latest change that was caused by update on account and triggering process builder. But still the workflow field update is not triggering.

Here is the rule criteria for the workflow field update:

```
OR(IsChanged( LastModifiedDate ),IsChanged( CreatedDate),NOT(ISBLANK(OwnerId)))
```

I can't understand what causes the workflow not to be triggered. I am wondering can the process builders even trigger a workflow field update, or I am making a mistake somewhere else?

Comment: Just use every time it is updated or created as the type and use the ownerid part as the criteria. If you do not want it on insert add !isNew() to the criteria.

Comment: @eric worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: great. Added it as answer. IIRC the lastmodifued and created date are done after the fact and do not trigger more updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change they type to whenever created or edited

Use the ownerid part in the criteria. If you want to exclude insert add !isNew() to the criteria